Itel Prime Tab 1 phone only shows the logo on boot
I got my Itel Prime Tab 1 fixed today and it only shows the logo. I went to fix the charging system, and it has been about 1 year since I last switched it on. When I charge it, only the logo shows.
I tried to factory reset it in recovery mode, but it did not work.
How to boot into the OS?
